# differentiate $\hat\theta$ by $\theta$ = zero or 1?

Tags: derivatives, regression, fisher-information

[image]

In this picture, $\hat\theta$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. You may assume 'f(x)' as a standard normal distribution.
the second line assume that, if you differentiate $\hat\theta$ by $\theta$, it becomes 0.
It means, $\hat\theta$ is just a constant number to $\theta$.
But isn't $\hat\theta$ a function of $\theta$? Because it imitates and follows $\theta$.
You may say that
$$\hat\theta + e = \theta+\epsilon$$
then, it is associated together, so differentiating $\hat\theta$ by $\theta$ will be 1, not 0.

How do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. but if we assume the 'null hypothesis' is "θ and θ^ have no relationship each other", it make sense. then the θ^ becomes just a constant number of θ.